# Adding horizontal space between 2 buttons using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am dynamically creating submit buttons using javascript. I wanted to know how to introduce horizontal spacing between every other button in the process.

My code is

```
var allFields = commonButtons.concat(extraFields);
for (var i = 0; i < allFields.length; i++) {
    var node = document.createElement("input");
    var btName = document.getElementById("submit-buttons");
    node.setAttribute('data-value', allFields[i]);
    node.setAttribute('class', "submitButton");
    node.setAttribute('type', "submit");
    node.setAttribute('id', "test");
    node.setAttribute('name', "");
    node.setAttribute('value', allFields[i]);
    var parent = document.getElementById('submit-buttons');
    parent.insertBefore(node, parent.childNodes[parent.childNodes.length - 2]);
}
```

How do I do this?

Comment: node.setAttribute('style', "margin: 0 10px;");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use CSS instead of Javascript. Anyway, you're adding a class to all buttons. Use following code:

```
.submitButton {
    margin: 0 10px;
}
```

Comment: Pretty much what I was going to say, however I would use `margin: 0px 10px;` instead as he only wants horizontal spacing.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the line below:

`node.style.marginTop='0px 10px';`

It will add style to your control.